# Search AD User via logon script in Powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, active-directory

I want to see all users that have a specific drive connected. We are working with logon scripts.

Now...in Powershell, I have the following code:

> Get-ChildItem \\logonserver\LogonBats -File -Filter *.bat |Select-String -Pattern
> 'Connect the S-Drive' -CaseSensitive

This code searches our Folder with all the logon scripts that contains the text for example 'Connect the S-Drive'.

The results looks something like this:

> \\logonserver\LogonBats\logon_Johnny_something.bat:1:rem "Connect the
> S-Drive" \\logonserver\LogonBats\logon_Tom_Jerry_something.bat:1:rem
> "Connect the S-Drive"
> \\logonserver\LogonBats\logon_I_dont_Know.bat:1:rem "Connect the
> S-Drive"

How can I get all the users (names) that uses the Logon script that I got beforehand?

I have something like this:

> get-ADUser -filter "scriptpath -eq 'Johnny_something.bat'"
> -Properties scriptpath| select name, samaccountname, scriptpath

But I want to search every logon script that I got in the code above.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `ScriptPath` attribute on your AD Users, does it contain only the `.bat` name or the complete UNC path as shown in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd grab the users from AD that have a login script assigned and that are enabled. Then take that list and find who has one of the specified scripts assigned.

```
$scriptlist = Get-ChildItem \\logonserver\LogonBats -File -Filter *.bat | Select-String -Pattern 'Connect the S-Drive' -CaseSensitive

# build regex search pattern
$search = $scriptlist.Filename -join '|'

# get enabled uses that have a logon script defined
$userlist = Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq '$true' -and scriptpath -like '*'" -Properties scriptpath

# find users that have the logon script assigned that we are looking for
$userlist | Where-Object scriptpath -Match $search
```

If you also want to see disabled just remove `Enabled -eq '$true'` from the `Get-AdUser call`. If the script names have special characters, you can use `[regex]::Escape()` to handle them

```
$scriptlist = Get-ChildItem \\logonserver\LogonBats -File -Filter *.bat | Select-String -Pattern 'Connect the S-Drive' -CaseSensitive

# build regex search pattern
$search = $scriptlist.Filename -join '|'

# get enabled uses that have a logon script defined
$userlist = Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq '$true' -and scriptpath -like '*'" -Properties scriptpath

# find users that have the logon script assigned that we are looking for
$userlist | Where-Object scriptpath -Match [regex]::Escape($search)
```